# Html.ActionLink showing query url instead of pretty url

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

The Html.ActionLink

```
<li> ${Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Edit(ViewData.Model.Id, ViewData.Model.Title), "Edit")} </li>
```

When created as html shows the URL to be `Edit/5006?title=One`  . How do I change this to a pretty URL like `Edit/5006/One` ?

My Edit Action method is

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string title)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488908/asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink-result-url-the-way-of-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a route setup:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithTitle",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
    new 
    { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Edit", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        title = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not depends on the function stamp, but it depends on the routing configuration.

```
routes.MapRoute("Edit",                                         // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",                   // URL with parameters 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first answer to this question: [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

The important point is that you have to make sure you're using the right overload for ActionLink().